# ModX Revo: Update sites base URL?

Tags: url, configuration, content-management-system, modx, modx-revolution

I developed a site for a client before a domain name was chosen. As a result, the URLs for the site pages look like:

```
http://host.mynost.net/~tempname/index.php?id=8
```

A domain name has now been purchased but if I click on any Wayfinder links it still uses the old path as above instead of, say:

```
http://domainname.com/index.php?id=8
```

I assume this is configured in the config.inc.php file, but I am unsure of what to change.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change `$modx_base_url= '/'` in `/core/config/config.inc.php` and if that is not enough - manually clean `/core/cache/` folder.

Comment: Check out all other paths in `config.inc.php`. You changed the location of modx installation?

Answer (score 4):

Four years later, I've dealt with the same thing for a few months, and was incredibly frustrated.

An updated answer to this issue would be navigating to `Settings (icon) > Context`, then choosing `Key > web (right click) > Update Context > Context Settings`.

Change `http_host` (ex. `localhost`) and `site_url` (ex. `http://localhost/`).

Now, from the top menu `Manage > Clear Cache` as well as `Manage > Clear Cache > Refresh URIs`.

It was like finding a pot of gold.

Comment: omg please let me hug you ... this was the solution <3 in german:
Eigenschaften -> Kontexte -> Site URL -> Rechtsklick -> Einstellungen bearbeiten -> unten bei Wert von http zu https

Answer (score 1):

I have a web on some super-old Modx version which I needed to temporarily set up for viewing, and I ran into this issue.

The way I changed the base URL is in the database:
**table:** `modx_context_setting`
**key:** `site_url`

Answer (score 0):

This outlines how to move modx to a new location ~ which is essentially what you have done.

http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Moving+Your+Site+to+a+New+Server

genereally you can get away with updating the config.inc.php & clearing the cache, but it's a good idea to go through the system setting table in the db looking for old paths, some packages do store path info in there.