# MODx, move to subfolder not working

Tags: php, apache, modx

I'm using an older version of MODx (not sure exactly, but it's the one with the "manager" folder) and it's currently living in the root of my server ... but I need to move it to a subdirectory called "clients"

I'm trying to figure out why even after I've moved all of the files, MODx keep referring to the root install... all assets are being loaded from the root install, all requests seem to be going through the root install...

Do I need to update `base_url` and `base_path` somewhere that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 1):

Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15015945/modx-revo-update-sites-base-url/15017385)? And if you move modx installation to another folder - check out these files and correct all paths inside

```
/config.core.php
/core/config/config.inc.php
/manager/config.core.php
/connectors/config.core.php
```